# Angular nested route with param "Cannot match any routes"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Here are the 3 routes I'm working on:

- `game/:id`
- `game/:id/pricing`
- `game/:id/history`

I'd like the `game/:id` to be the parent view, and house a `<router-outlet>` for the children to render inside of it. However, I keep getting this error: **Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'game/1/history'.**

Any help is appreciated.

### Router Module:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { GameComponent } from "./game.component";
import { GamePricingComponent } from './game-pricing.component';
import { GameHistoryComponent } from './game-history.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'game/:id', component: GameComponent, children: [
    { path: 'pricing', component: GamePricingComponent, outlet: 'game' },
    { path: 'history', component: GameHistoryComponent, outlet: 'game' }
  ]},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    GameComponent,
    GamePricingComponent,
    GameHistoryComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class RoutingModule {}
```

### GameComponent:

The `game/:id` route is the parent view, which has a `<router-outlet name="game">` inside of it for the children (pricing & history) to render into.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  template: `
<div>Game stuff</div>
<router-outlet name="game"></router-outlet>
`
})
export class GameComponent {}
```

### RootModule

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RoutingModule } from "./routing.module";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export default class AppModule { }
```

### AppComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
<div class="base">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
`,
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Comment: can you put all your routing configuration please

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine there's not much else to the routing... but as requested, I added in my `RootModule` and `AppComponent` which shows the importation of the module and the nameless `<router-outlet>`

Comment: @tonylefler were you able to solve this?

Comment: @naoru - kind of - see my answer for explanation

Comment: @tonylefler i have it working with just one router, thats easy, i need to load two different views to two different routers based on the URL.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a (long) while, I was able to solve this by removing the naming for the `<router-outlet>`. Turns out, single child router outlets 'just work' - so naming isn't required...

However, as of writing this, I'm still unaware of how to use router outlet naming within child routes. If anyone wants to elaborate here, I'd be more than appreciative. (maybe naming only works if there's more than 1 outlet at the same level?)

Comment: You'd think naming the outlet would just always work... Or maybe you have to name all of them? Even the main router-outlet?

Comment: This saved me a lot of time... I wish angular error logger could me more precise on how to solve the errors.

Comment: Another interesting sidenote - if you don't add child components to declarations of any NgModule, it won't render them. Which makes sense but it won't also show any error whatsoever (which does not make sense..)