# Navigate programmatically with relativeTo a nested route result in "Error: Cannot match any routes."

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

My router looks like Full example here in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfty2q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.model.ts):

```
const eventChildren = [    
    { path: 'new', component: FooEditComponent }    
];

const appRoutes : Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/foos' , pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'foos/:year/:month/:day', component: FoosComponent, children: eventChildren}
]
```

When the user navigate from the URL bar by pasting this address in the URL bar: https://angular-tfty2q.stackblitz.io/foos/2020/4/20/new everything works as expected (The `FooEditComponent` child component is being rendered as expected).

But when the user first navigate to https://angular-tfty2q.stackblitz.io/foos/2020/4/20/, and then try to navigate to the same "New" route address (programmatically) from the `HeaderComponent` (parent) by clicking the "New" `li` with:

`header.component.html`:

```
<ul>
  <li style="cursor: pointer;"><a (click)="onNewClick()">New</a></li>
</ul>
```

`header.component.ts`:

```
onNewClick() {
    this.router.navigate(['new'], {relativeTo: this.route});
}
```

It resulted in error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'new'

I already tried various similar answers like ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49402389/6844481),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46482993/6844481),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42774680/6844481)) with no progress.

Comment: You may not need this `{relativeTo: this.route}`

Comment: try `['./new']`, e.g. `this.router.navigate(['./new'],relativeTo: this.activatedRoute)` -I use activatedRouter because in constructor I use `private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute`-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the `li` to foos.component.html

```
<ul>
    <li style="cursor: pointer;"><a [routerLink]="['./new']">New</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Working Demo](https://angular-7z4mbb.stackblitz.io/foos/2020/4/20)

Comment: Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7z4mbb?embed=1&file=src/app/foos/foos.component.html